# What is the general way of finding a probability that Markov chain goes to absorbing state

Tags: markov-chains, transition-matrix

Given an NxN matrix like the on shown here:
$$
\mathbf{M} = \matrix{~ \\
              & 0 & 0.5 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.5\\
              & 0.5 & 0 & 0 & 0.3 & 0.2 & 0 \\
              & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
              & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
              & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
              & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
              }
$$
What is the general way of finding the probability of going from `state_0` (represented by first row) into each absorbing state (`s2`, `s3`, `s4`, `s5` in this case) for any NxN matrix, if it is guaranteed that the matrix will have at least one absorbing state?

Comment: Wait this cannot possibly be a matrix for Markov Chain can it? Simply because the row sum is not always 1?

Comment: @JustWandering, my bad, forgot to add ones to absorbing rows. I will edit now